# How to get the name of a textView?

Tags: android, textbox, textview

I have the following situation: 
I have an activity(A) that calls a new activity(B) window. So in activity (B) I have 5 Text Fields(textbox) with their names (5 TextViews) which the user have to fill in. I want to return to the previous activity(A) with string containing the names of which textBoxes were filled (not the value put in the textbox just the name). Now my problem is how to do this? I know that for the passing of data from activity (B) to activity(A) I have to use:

```
  Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
  // TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
  finish();
```

and retrieve the data in activity (A) with:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch(requestCode) {
case (MY_CHILD_ACTIVITY) : {
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    // TODO Extract the data returned from the child Activity.
  }
  break;
 } 
 }
}
```

But I dont know wjat to pass since the name in front of the textbox is not connected to the textBox so how can I know which textbox has been filled and what name should I pass back?

Comment: views unlike dogs and people dont have names

Comment: Isnt the ID of the view containing the name?

Comment: no, id is an int like 123456

Comment: So at least is there a way to say which text box was filled?

Comment: and return it to Activity(A)?

Comment: there is getText() method use it to get the old and new values and compare them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot say which editbox correspondents to which textfield (name)

you have to remember this by yourself:
if i have something like this:

```
----------------------------
| Firstname |    | [EditBox] |
----------------------------
| Lastname  |    | [EditBox] |
----------------------------
```

if the first box is called `box1` and the second `box2`,
how should i know that `box1` is a firstname and `box2` a lastname?
in now way.

so because you have designed the layout, you also know that `box1` is *firstname*

so if the user filled in his first and lastname or even if he didn't fill in anything and then goes back to your `Activity A`,
you can just put the editboxes texts as extras from B to A. and because you know what editbox1 corresponds to, you can pass it back with a key YOU know:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("firstname", firstname.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("lastname", lastname.getText().toString());
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

and in on activity result get the values youve just set, with:

```
String first = intent.getExtras().getString("firstname", null);
```

and same for lastname

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of a `View` via:

[`Resources#getResourceName(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName%28int%29) or [`Resources#getResourcesEntryName(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName%28int%29)

`getResources().getResourceName(theView.getId());`
`getResources().getResourceEntryName(theView.getId()));`

You may also want to consider using [`setHint(CharSequence)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29) to label the `EditText` instead of using `TextView`

Or, you could group the `TextView` and `EditText` in a layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/the_first_name_group">
   <TextView android:text="The first name" />
   <EditView android:id=@+id/the_first_name_value />
</LinearLayout>
```

and add code such as:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) theFirstNameValue.getParent();
getResources().getResourceEntryName(parent.getId());
```

which would return `the_first_name_group`